# Get values from a pair RDD in Python

Tags: pyspark, rdd

How to get value1 and value2 from a pair RDD of the form : `[('key', (value1, value2))]`.

Answer (score 0):

You could use mapValues function to solve this. Consider that the productRDD has the structure:

```
[('someKey', (10, 20))]
```

Then in order to find a new RDD(resultRDD) which hold the product of values in the productRDD we use:

```
resultRDD = productRDD.mapValues(lambda value: value[0] * (value[1]))
```

The resultRDD will have the following data:

```
[('someKey', 200)]
```